# How to format background images HTML regarding size and repetition

Tags: html

I am currently working on a school project in which we are tasked to make a website. I am attempting to make a background image stay at a specific size no matter the screen size while making the image repeat itself vertically.

I have looked far and wide attempting to find an answer to this question and couldn't find anything which helps- "Your my only hope"

I am new to Stack Overflow so I hope I have formatted this correctly.
Thanks- DH

Example:

```
body {
    background-image: url("background.png");
    background-size: auto;

    background-position: auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Glad to have you aboard :) You've *almost* posted correctly. What's missing is what you have tried so far. Please add a code example of your code and narrow your question down to a specific issue you're having, rather than asking about a bigger problem. (That would actually be considered off-topic)

Comment: Write something at first and share it and we try to help. Now how should we now what do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
 background-image: url("path/image.jpg");
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
 background-size: cover;
```

Background-repeat has given value repeat-y  image vertically as you want it, This will repeat the image vertically on your page and background size property can take. cover, values in pixel or in percentage. I think you should play with it in % to fit for you screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the size for your background using `background-size` property, and you can repeat the background using `background-repeat` property through CSS. For example look at the following snippet. The original size of the image is around 3264x2448. But I have mentioned in my code 150x100 and repeating the image vertically using `repeat-y` property. I have applied the entire background for the body element and align it horizontally top and vertically center.

```css
body {
  background-image:url("http://myanmareiti.org/sites/default/files/sample-5_0.jpg");
  background-repeat:repeat-y;
  background-size:150px 100px;
  background-position:top center;
}
```

```html
<div>
Something HRere
</div>
```